# C# Supersimpletcp Allow any client to have only one connection

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcp, tcpserver

i am using Supersimpletcp C# library and TCP server code is here:

```
using SuperSimpleTcp;

void Main(string[] args)
{
  // instantiate
  SimpleTcpServer server = new SimpleTcpServer("127.0.0.1:9000");

  // set events
  server.Events.ClientConnected += ClientConnected;
  server.Events.ClientDisconnected += ClientDisconnected;
  server.Events.DataReceived += DataReceived;

  // let's go!
  server.Start();

  // once a client has connected...
  server.Send("[ClientIp:Port]", "Hello, world!");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ClientConnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"[{e.IpPort}] client connected");
}

static void ClientDisconnected(object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"[{e.IpPort}] client disconnected: {e.Reason}");
}

static void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"[{e.IpPort}]: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data.Array, 0, e.Data.Count)}");
}
```

On TCP Server implementation, I want to **allow any client to have just one connection**, if a previously connected client reconnects, previous connection must die, how can I provide it?
I researched on google and could not find any solution, documentation or tutorial for supersimpletcp.

If you guys have any suggestion, any kind of simple TCP library that provides good configuration oppurtunities etc., feel free to tell me.

Comment: Create your own class that inherits the TCPClient.   Make it static and if client is not null and is connected disconnect before adding new connection.